# How to get an arbitrary method signature using reflection?

Tags: go, reflection

I can use an extra pair of eyes solving this challenge, [playground here](https://go.dev/play/p/NL1i3BazSx1)

Ultimate goal is to register functions and struct public functions into an activity manager and execute them via function name, so something along the lines of:

```golang
   pool := map[string]interface{
       "Sample": func(ctx context.Context) error,
       "Sample2": func(ctx context.Context, args ...interface{}) error,
       "SampleFromStruct": func(ctx context.Context) error,
       "Sample2FromStruct": func(ctx context.Context, args ...interface{}) error,
   }
```

the functions looks like:

```golang
func Sample(ctx context.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("exec Sample")
    return nil
}

func Sample2(ctx context.Context, args interface{}) error {
    arguments := struct {
        Foo string `json:"foo"`
        Bar string `json:"bar"`
    }{}

    b, err := json.Marshal(args)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &arguments); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println("exec Sample2 with args", arguments)

    return nil
}

// and same but with struct
type ActivityInStruct struct {
    Bar string
}

func (a *ActivityInStruct) SampleInStruct(ctx context.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("Value of Bar", a.Bar)
    return Sample(ctx)
}

func (a *ActivityInStruct) Sample2InStruct(ctx context.Context, args interface{}) error {
    fmt.Println("Value of Bar", a.Bar)
    return Sample2(ctx, args)
}
```

Said this, I got it working with functions with the followed implementation:

```golang
type activityManager struct {
    fnStorage map[string]interface{}
}

func (lm *activityManager) Register(fn interface{}) error {
    fnName := strings.Split((runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(fn).Pointer()).Name()), ".")
    name := fnName[len(fnName)-1]
    lm.fnStorage[name] = fn
    return nil
}

func (lm *activityManager) Exec(ctx context.Context, fnName string, args ...interface{}) error {
    fn, ok := lm.fnStorage[fnName]
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("activity %s not found", fnName)
    }

    if signatureCtx, ok := fn.(func(context.Context) error); ok {
        return signatureCtx(ctx)
    }

    if signatureWithArgument, ok := fn.(func(context.Context, interface{}) error); ok {
        return signatureWithArgument(ctx, args[0])
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("signature for %s not supported", fnName)

}
```

so the Execution looks like this:

```golang
func NewManager() *activityManager {
    return &activityManager{
        fnStorage: map[string]interface{}{},
    }
}

/*...*/
    ctx := context.Background()
    manager := NewManager()
    manager.Register(Sample)
    manager.Register(Sample2)

    if err := manager.Exec(ctx, "Sample"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Sample error", err.Error())
        return
    }

    args1 := map[string]interface{}{
        "foo": "isFoo",
        "bar": "isBar",
    }
    if err := manager.Exec(ctx, "Sample2", args1); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Sample2 error", err.Error())
        return
    }
```

However, to register something like this:

```golang
func (lm *activityManager) RegisterStruct(fn interface{}) error {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(fn)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        m := t.Method(i)
        if m.IsExported() {

            /*
                               This won't work cause m.Type are
                               func(*main.ActivityInStruct, context.Context, interface {}) error
                                           func(*main.ActivityInStruct, context.Context) error

                                          instead of
                                          func(context.Context, interface {}) error
                                          func(context.Context) error
            */

            lm.fnStorage[m.Name] = m.Func
        }
    }

    return nil
}



/* Register Activity from Public methods in struct */
    activitiesStruct := &ActivityInStruct{
        Bar: "I'm the Bar",
    }

    manager.RegisterStruct(activitiesStruct)
```

I cant get this to work cause the reflection shows the method signature like this instead, `func(*main.ActivityInStruct, context.Context, interface {}) error`

Any idea how to go around that? [the full playground is here](https://go.dev/play/p/NL1i3BazSx1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [Value.Method](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Method) to get the [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values).

```
func (lm *activityManager) RegisterStruct(fn interface{}) error {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        m := t.Method(i)
        if m.IsExported() {
            lm.fnStorage[m.Name] = v.Method(i).Interface()
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: champion! thank u so much! this is exactly what I needed it!